# C# Marshal uint*& parameter

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, marshalling

I'M browsing through the whole stackoverflow forum but I'm quite unsure if my marshalling solution fits to my problem.

I got a c++ method returning an array of integer via a parameter. The prototype is the following:

```
method1(uint aId, uint*& aNewIntArray, uint& aNewIntArrayCount);
```

I marshal the parameters like:

```
method1(UInt32 aId, ref UIntPtr aNewIntArray, ref UInt64 aNewIntArrayCount);
```

I marshal uint*& to ref UIntPtr but I'm not very sure if this is correct and while i not found another one having the same problem i'll ask on myself.

Another idea is: Is it possible to marshal int* and int& parameter the same way using

```
ref UInt32
```

? Or did I need to use UIntPtr / IntPtr without a "ref" Keyword? 
In this case I would prefer to use **ref** instead of **out** to avoid the C++ uses a not initialized int reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C++ method is allocating an array of integers and returning a pointer to the first element in `aNewIntArray`. Therefore the match C# definition for that parameter is

```
ref IntPtr aNewIntArray
```

You used `UIntPtr` which is basically equivalent. I think you are under the impression that `UIntPtr` is what you use if the underlying array is unsigned but that is not the case. This is effectively a `void*` pointer and you will have to use `Marshal.Copy` to transfer to a C# array, `uint[]`.

Note that since the `aNewIntArray` really is an out parameter I think you should declare it as such

You also have declared the final parameter incorrectly. It is a 32 bit integer.

I would therefore declare the C# function like this:

```
method1(uint aId, out IntPtr aNewIntArray, out uint aNewIntArrayCount);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, regarding the parameter types i'll have to give further information. The C++ method parameters are wrapped through macros. This means an uint as stated here is declared as **unsigned long** and the 3rd parameter is declared internally as **unsigned __int64**, considering this information, would you say the types I declared fit better than yours?

Comment: Well, I can only answer what's in the question!  ;-)  But if they C++ declarations are as you say then, in C#, param one is `uint` or `UInt32` and param 2 is `ulong` or `UInt64`.

Comment: for sure you can :) but i wanted to keep the macro issue beside in the first step :)

Comment: I don't think so. I think that's for passing values in the other direction, managed to unmanaged. IntPtr is fine.

Comment: I've red that someone was saying there is a major difference between passing output parameters using ref and or out to a C++ DLL. According to this guy, passing pointers will lead to the fac,t that only the memory cell of the pointer it self will be passed not the memory the pointer points to, therefore pointers, strings and integers shal lbe passed using the "ref" keyword to make sure that the value will be passed not only the memory cell pointing to/referencing it. What do you know about this?

Comment: That makes little sense to me. Perhaps you are referring to how strings and arrays are marshalled automatically. But in this case that's not relevant since you are passing a pointer to memory that you are marshalling. In fact nothing would break if you used `ref`, but you'd just have to assign the value before you call the procedure. Rather pointless.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer David. I was just a bit confused about this because I could not really imagine an error coming up in this routine. Thanks !